# Puppet doesn't configure MySQL

Tags: mysql, puppet, mariadb

I have a following Puppet class using `puppetlabs/mysql` module:

```
class hg_playground::makowals::brains::db {

class { '::mysql::client':
    package_name => 'mariadb',
}

$override_options = {
    'mysqld' => {
        'log-bin' => '',
        'server-id' => $mysql_server_id,
  }
}
class { '::mysql::server':
    package_name => 'mariadb-server',
    root_password           => 'TESTOWY',
    remove_default_accounts => true,
    override_options        => $override_options,
}

mysql_user { 'slave_user@localhost':
    ensure => 'present',
    password_hash => mysql_password('master_replication'),
}

mysql_grant { 'slave_user@localhost/*.*':
    ensure => 'present',
    options => ['GRANT'],
    privileges => ['REPLICATION SLAVE'],
    table => '*.*',
    user => 'slave_user@localhost',
}

mysql_database { 'somedb':
    ensure => 'present',
}
}
```

What happens in there is

- mariadb-server is being installed correctly
- root password to db IS NOT set
- in `/root/.my.cnf` I have `password='TESTOWY'`
- neither new user nor database are not created

Of course running agent does not produce any errors. How to start debugging in this situation? Notices from running the class don't show anything interesting:

```
notice  /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Install/Package[mysql-server]/ensure    created
notice  /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Config/File[mysql-config-file]/content  content changed '{md5}54dc3e561e817f9c0a376a58383eb013' to '{md5}ff09a4033f718f08f69da17f0aa86652'
notice  /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Service/Service[mysqld]/ensure  ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
notice  /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/File[/root/.my.cnf]/ensure    defined content as '{md5}042e1a46bc15a260a349dbbe1bac8e71'
```

Comment: What notices/errors do you get when you run: class { '::mysql::server': ... }?

Comment: I don't see nothing interesting there - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Dz4JFbQr

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `centos 5` and mariadb is not in main repo, so I don't specified `package_name` and I tested your class and works, the only thing that I added is require in `mysql::server` class and I used mysql::db class for create the DB.

```
class hg_playground::makowals::brains::db {
class { '::mysql::client':
    package_name => 'mariadb',
}

$override_options = {
    'mysqld' => {
        'log-bin' => '',
        'server-id' => $mysql_server_id,
  }
}
class { '::mysql::server':
    package_name => 'mariadb-server',
    root_password           => 'TESTOWY',
    remove_default_accounts => true,
    override_options        => $override_options,
}

mysql_user { 'slave_user@localhost':
    ensure => 'present',
    password_hash => mysql_password('master_replication'),
}

mysql_grant { 'slave_user@localhost/*.*':
    ensure => 'present',
    options => ['GRANT'],
    privileges => ['REPLICATION SLAVE'],
    table => '*.*',
    user => 'slave_user@localhost',
}

mysql_database { 'somedb':
    ensure => 'present',
    require => Class['mysql::server']
  }
}
```

Puppet execution output.

```
=> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for centos7.example.com in environment testing in 2.97 seconds
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Client::Install/Package[mysql_client]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Install/Package[mysql-server]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Config/File[mysql-config-file]/content: content changed '{md5}54dc3e561e817f9c0a376a58383eb013' to '{md5}40a2060d1d62cb5c3f33e5e74be19889'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Installdb/Exec[mysql_install_db]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Service/Service[mysqld]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/Mysql_user[root@localhost]/password_hash: defined 'password_hash' as '*416F1598B4E5F9CD0DBFC2E35867FA1F96EBF4F5'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/File[/root/.my.cnf]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}cd27be3d51dcd48e92de9df7e894accb'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Account_security/Mysql_user[root@127.0.0.1]/ensure: removed
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Account_security/Mysql_user[root@::1]/ensure: removed
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Account_security/Mysql_user[@localhost]/ensure: removed
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Account_security/Mysql_user[root@centos7.example.com]/ensure: removed
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Account_security/Mysql_user[@centos7.example.com]/ensure: removed
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Account_security/Mysql_database[test]/ensure: removed
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hg_playground::Makowals::Brains::Db/Mysql_user[slave_user@localhost]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hg_playground::Makowals::Brains::Db/Mysql_grant[slave_user@localhost/*.*]/privileges: privileges changed ['USAGE'] to 'REPLICATION SLAVE'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hg_playground::Makowals::Brains::Db/Mysql_grant[slave_user@localhost/*.*]/options: defined 'options' as 'GRANT'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hg_playground::Makowals::Brains::Db/Mysql_database[somedb]/ensure: created
```

Comment: Well, the problem is definitely with `package_name => 'mariadb'`, but does not help with solving issue anyway

Comment: @MateuszKowalski Have you tried using the class I posted?

Comment: Yes, but I want to use mariadb-server in my deployment, no mysql-server

Comment: @MateuszKowalski what distributation are you using?

Comment: CentOS 7.1, it's supposed to be supported

Comment: @MateuszKowalski I did test using Centos 7 using your class and mariadb packages and the only thing you are missing is "require => Class['mysql::server']" because you need to be sure, the mariadb-server is begin installed first, I edited my answer and you can see that class that I used.

Comment: I did a test using exactly the same code as you pasted and it is not working - package is installed, but nothing gets configured at all

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql::server class should have a package_name attribute that includes a version.

```
class{ 'mysql::server':
  package_name     => "mariadb-server-${mariadb_version}",
  ...
}
```

Use e.g. `apt-cache search mariadb-server` to look at what the package name looks like, assuming you have already taken care of adding a repository version that provides what you want.  There's separate repositories for different version families of mariadb.